# calling isFinishing() function is caused nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-activity

I try in my app to check in a function if the activity is finishing or not ,to use this thing in other activity, but when I want to print the returnvalue isFinisging I get nullpointerException,although it works fine without log statement, I hope I could explain what the problem , please if anyone know what that happened tell me.
this is the function.

```
public static boolean isFinish(){

  Log.e("finishing", String.valueOf(activity.isFinishing()));
  return activity.isFinishing(); }
```

when I put comment on log statement everything is fine.

Comment: What's `activity`? And how's `isFinishing()` defined?

Comment: Use `getBaseActivity().isFinishing();` or `getApplicationActivity().isFinishing();` activity can be anything, define what it is here.

Comment: Looks like `activity` is a static member. Well take this advice: *"Never ever hold a static reference to any of your activities"*. I know it looks easiest solution for some problems, but you'll eventually have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If Android's `Log` gets called with a null argument it will cause the `NullpointerException` in the title.
2. There is a call of method `public static String valueOf(char data[])`, which source code is as follows:

   `public static String valueOf(char data[]) {`
       `return new String(data);`
   `}`

If `activity.isFinishing()` returns `null` there is a possibility for `NullpointerException`.

Thus check what is the result of `activity.isFinishing()`.